# kde profiles for home, work movie watching etc

Tags: kde, users, screensaver

Is there a way to configure different KDE config modes for different profiles?
when i am watching a movie i don't want to see a screen saver or lock screen, but when working at my PC i want to start a screen saver after 15 minutes. 
Also display dimming and similar settings are different.
I don't want to create several users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Activities**

The KDE is having the Activities: http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma -> http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Activities

You could use the Activities as the profiles.

**Example**

Make the Activities for the home, work, movie watching...

[image]

Set the activity power management settings...

[image]